# Alert when the next click on a button is pressed in less than 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am new with javascript. I want to display a message in the client side if a person press a button continuously. So I think it is better to use a javascript code to show an Alert message if someone pressed two times on the button in less than two seconds. How may I do it? I know just showing an Alert message is like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
  <button onclick="myVar = setTimeout(myFunction, 2000)">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function myFunction() {
  alert('This is an Alert Message!');
}
```

Comment: you can just disable your button after click durring 2s

Comment: Why? What does the button do, why shouldn't it be clicked multiple times? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```js
var t = 0;
function myFunction() {
  if(t == 1) {
    alert('This is an Alert Message!');
  }
  t=1;
  setTimeout(function(){
    t=0;
  },2000)
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
     <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: While I like your approach, I fear it does not help the OP to learn what is happening...

Comment: i don't understand what you want to say.

Comment: thank you very much . Is there any way to disable this Alert message to be clicked with pressing the Enter Key? My button is clicked by pressing the Enter Key, So the user can do it again after pressing Enter. Co can run code snippest and press enter continuously to see what I am saying.

Comment: See, @KrupeshKotecha, the OP needs more than functional code. We must help him LEARN what is happening.

Comment: Alert windows are provided by the browser, we cannot interfere with their functionality.

Comment: Isn't here away to prevent it to be disappeared after pressing the Enter Key? Set focus or anything else?

Comment: No. Your website is running within a browser, you could say the browser is the host. You cannot change host behavior with a website running inside it.

Comment: There should be a way to show the message in another way to be able to close it just with mouse click.

Comment: will sure add description next time. @Alexander

Comment: If you just want it to be closed with a mouse click, you cannot rely on the alert, but must write your own.

Comment: you have to use any other plugin that provides functionality like javascript popup

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKbrKL visit this link. your example with custom dialog